# Quero pesquisar datas no MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Preciso pesquisar detalhes de uma tabela criando uma procedure e utilizando mês e ano como variáveis, mas não sei como eu poderia fazer isso, a coluna dataPedido está definida como DATETIMEpensei em algo assim, mas não tenho a mínima ideia do que colocar depois do "LIKE".

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE buscaPedido(IN y int, m int)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Y, M INT;
        SET @Y =y ,@M = m;
        SELECT * FROM pedido 
        WHERE dataPedido LIKE ... ;
    END;
$$
```

Comment: Se seu campo é do tipo DATETIME então não deve utilizar LIKE para comparar. Se deseja apenas mês e ano então utilize a função EXTRACT para obter o mês e o ano e compare utilizando o operador de igualdade.

Comment: Consegui aqui, agora preciso pesquisar num intervalo de datas usando mês e dia

Comment: Então creio que você deva estudar sobre o operador BETWEEN. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between